# Why is $\varepsilon=\frac{W_{chemical}}{q}=\Delta V_{-\to+} $ the emf of a battery?

Tags: charge, potential, work, batteries, chemical-potential

In my book, the electromotive force (emf) of a battery is defined as follows $\varepsilon: = \frac{W_{chemical}}{q}$. The book then states that for an ideal battery, $\varepsilon = \Delta V_{-\to+}$, which is the change in potential of a positive charge on moving from the negative terminal to positivee terminal. My question is why is that the case?

**Attempt**

We know by definition that $\Delta V_{-\to+} = \frac{\Delta U_{-\to+}}{q}$ where $\Delta U$ is change in electrical potential energy.

Lets now let our closed system to be the charge and the two terminals But by energy principle we know that 
$\Delta E_{-\to+}=W_{ext}$, where $W_{ext}$ is work done from outside the system, which in this case is the work done by the chemical processes inside the battery.

$\Delta E_{-\to+}=\Delta U_{-\to+}+\Delta K_{-\to+}=W_{chemical }$ **but the charge start with kinetic energy $0$ and ends on the other terminal with kinetic energy also $0$ thus $\Delta K_{-\to+}=0$**

$\therefore \Delta U_{-\to+}=W_{chemical} \implies \Delta V_{-\to+}=\frac{W_{chemical}}{q}=\varepsilon$

My doubt is in the bold reasoning above, I don't really know why that is a correct statement, I just kind of made it up in order to make the proof work, moreover since the charge continues in the circuit that line of reasoning shouldn't be correct since the charge doesn't stop but continues moving in the circuit. Also why define $\varepsilon=\frac{W_{chemical}}{q}$ and not $\varepsilon= \Delta V_{-\to+}$? for me it seems a bit more natural to define it as the latter. Or are those two definitions equivalent since one can be implied by the other?

Thanks for any Help.

Answer (score 0):

Without all the context I assume that the book is trying to make a distinction between a "real" battery, and an "ideal" battery.

An ideal battery would deliver the same voltage regardless of the current draw.

A real battery essentially has an internal resistance. Thus as the current increases the voltage decreases.

Comment: but then would my derivation be correct?